# Handlebars inside of Markdown, inside of HAML

Tags: haml, markdown, mustache

I know that this is a very non-standard use case, but I'm chaining HAML, Markdown, and Handlebars (in SproutCore 2.0), and I'm 1 step away from 'beautiful' code.  Intermingling HAML, Markdown, and Javascript is less ideal than it could be.  If I wanted to add a post-filter to the entire output of HAML, replacing `{{text}}` with `<script>{{text}}</script>`, what would be the best way to do it?

I could just hack on a post-build step after `haml`, but I'd like to turn it into something that I can give back to the SproutCore community.

I want to replace

```
%body
  javascript:
    {{handlebars}}
```

With

```
%body
  {{handlebars}}
```

Which would give me

```
<body>
  <script>{{handlebars}}</script>
</body>
```

However, I also want this to work when embedded within markdown.  For example,

```
%body
  markdown:
    # Hello, {{handlebars}}
```

Currently, the only way to get this is

```
%body
  markdown:
    # Hello, <script>{{handlebars}}</script>
```

Which would product

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello, <script>{{handlebars}}</script></h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting the same issue much, much later, it appears that there's not a good solution for this with HAML.  However, Jade does just about everything that I want.

http://jade-lang.com/

### Input

```
html
  script(type='text/x-handlebars')
    :markdown
      *Hello, {{handlebars}}!*
```

### Output

```
<html>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars"><p><em>Hello, {{handlebars}}!</em></p>
  </script>
</html>
```